# Jagged Quote of IV for BlackVarianceSurface

Tags: python, quantlib

I am following [this](http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/volatility-smile-heston-model-calibration-quantlib-python.html) example and trying to adapt it to my needs.

In the section of code:

```
implied_vols[i][j] = data[j][i]

implied_vols = ql.Matrix(len(strikes), len(expiration_dates))
for i in range(implied_vols.rows()):
    for j in range(implied_vols.columns()):
        implied_vols[i][j] = data[j][i]
  [1]: http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/volatility-smile-heston-model-calibration-quantlib-python.html
```

This assumes the `IV` `matrix` has all corresponding `strikes` for a given expiry. In fact, the [mass] `quote` is often stored in a `dictionary` instead of an `array` exactly for this reason.

For example in the `SPX`, we have different `strike` increments at different `expiration`. So some `strikes` are empty for one expiry but not another. I realize I can force the situation by making the `matrix` cell always have numerical value, but I am assuming that inserting a 0 at a given `strike/expiry` is a bad idea. Alternatively, forcing all `expiry` to the least common denominator of `strikes` between the `expiry` throws out lots of data.

What happens if the `volatility` quotes you have are not square and you don't want to throw out data when building a `ql.Matrix` to hand to `BlackVarianceSurface`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no ready-made solution.  As you say filling the missing cells with 0 is a bad idea; but filling them by interpolating manually the missing values should work.  The way to do it probably depends on how sparse your data is...

Comment: Thanks Luigi. Manually you mean by hand? It would take forever. Could I entice you to write an example in python of how to go about it?

Comment: I'm not sure I have one.  It depends on how sparse your data is: if you're missing one or two points per expiry, I suppose you can interpolate the surrounding points.  But if the matrix is very sparse, you'll need some kind of model.  I'd suggest looking into the literature.

Comment: Thanks Luigi for the tip.